# Solution of $ty'' +(2t+3)y' +(t+3)y = 3e^{-t}$ via Laplace transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

A recent question which was put on hold due to lack of context by the OP was the following:

> Solve the following ODE using Laplace transforms.
>
> $$ty'' +(2t+3)y' +(t+3)y = 3e^{-t}, \qquad y(0)=0$$

Putting the equation into the form

$$t(y^{\prime\prime}+2y^\prime+y)+3(y^\prime+y)=3e^{-t} $$

which has $y_c=ce^{-t}$ as a solution of its complementary equation immediately suggests $y=Ate^{-t}$ as a particular solution.
And this is borne out by substitution, with $A=1$. Applying the initial condition yields the solution

$$ y=te^{-t} $$

So why would the original OP want the equation solved using Laplace transforms?

**Is there a shorter path using Laplace transforms than the following?**

Use the fact that $(3e^{-t})^\prime+3e^{-t}=0$ to get the homogeneous equation
$$ [t(y^{\prime\prime}+2y^\prime+y)+3(y^\prime+y)]^\prime+[t(y^{\prime\prime}+2y^\prime+y)+3(y^\prime+y)]=0 $$
This simplifies to the homogeneous equation
$$ 
t(y^{\prime\prime\prime}+3y^{\prime\prime}+3y^\prime+y)+4(y^{\prime\prime}+2y^\prime+y)=0 $$
Taking the Laplace transform of this involves quite a bit of tedium which I will spare the reader, but yields the following:
\begin{eqnarray}  
   (s+1)^3Y^\prime+2(s+1)^2Y&=&0\\\  
   (s+1)^2Y^\prime+2(s+1)Y&=&0\\\  
   \left[(s+1)^2Y\right]^\prime&=&0\\\  
   Y&=&\frac{c}{(s+1)^2}\\\  
   y&=&cte^{-t}  
   \end{eqnarray}

So, with $c=1$, yielding the same solution found much more easily by inspection.

Comment: Probably it is suggested by the assignment? It is not uncommon to find such questions in the introductory chapters of subjects like Control System. With transformation tables given, doing in OP's way is at least more systematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping in mind that

$$
\mathcal{L}(t\mathcal{D}(y)) = -\frac{d}{ds}\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{D}(y)) 
$$

assuming null initial conditions and applying this in

$$
t \mathcal{D}^2y + \mathcal{D}y = 3e^{-t}
$$

we have

$$
-\frac{d}{ds}\left((s+1)^2 Y\right)+(s+1)Y = \frac{3}{s+1}
$$

or

$$
-Y'+\frac{1}{s+1}Y = \frac{3}{(s+1)^3}
$$

the homogeneous gives

$$
Y_h = \frac{c_1}{s+1}
$$

and the particular

$$
Y_p = \frac{1}{(s+1)^2}
$$

hence

$$
y(t) = (c_1+t)e^{-t}
$$

not difficult at all. Now if $y(0) = 0$ then

$$
y(t) = te^{-t}
$$